# React Native socket.io disconnects when app is on background mode

Tags: react-native

I am making a react native app for android devices using socket.io-client. Everything works fine but when the app goes on background mode (e.g. an other app launched) the socket connections disconnects from the server (app emits 'disconnect' event).
What is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. Have you tried anything that seems to work?

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: guys did anything work for you?

Comment: unfortunately at the moment the best way is make service in native android code

Comment: any recent updates?

Answer (score -2):

In the disconnect event of the socket I reconnect it, if user is not logging out.

```
socketInstance.on('disconnect', (err) => {
    console.log('SOCKET DISCONNECT', err);
    var deauthorize = store.getState().auth.account.deauthorize;
    if (!deauthorize) {
        store.dispatch(NotificationActions.addNotificationAction('SOCKET DISCONNECT'));    
        store.dispatch(AppActions.shouldConnectAction());                    
        store.dispatch(CommunicationActions.connectSocketAction());          
    }      
});
```