# react-native - does socket.io work when android/ios app in background?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sockets

I am dealing with the `socket.io` for react native app. Following, I am researching about making the `socket.io` work although Android/iOS app is in background.

According to my research, there are some useful links from stackoverflow:

- [How to run socket.io in the background on iOS in a React Native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458549/how-to-run-socket-io-in-the-background-on-ios-in-a-react-native-app)
- [React Native socket.io disconnects when app is on background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607708/react-native-socket-io-disconnects-when-app-is-on-background-mode)

Both of them told me that we can't achieve this in iOS. However, these posts are kinda old, so I am hoping that Apple and Google may consider and give us a way to do it.

Please let me know if you have any idea about how to make the `socket.io` work in background for Android/iOS.

Many thanks!